# "Property"-like methods instead of getters & setters in C++?

Tags: c++, properties, getter-setter

Situation:

```
class Person {
public:
     int& age();
     int age() const;
private:
     int m_age;
};
```

I don't know if this works as I think, so my first question is this:

- With these methods, can I create C# like **"properties"**? I mean:

  - With the **first** method I can implement what should happen when something **changes the value** of m_age.
  - With the **second** one I can implement what should happend when something **uses the value** of m_age.

Example:

```
Person p;
p.age() = 15; //first method is called?
std::cout << p.age(); //second method?
```

I'm starting to think that this is full of stupidity which is based on mixing operator overloading and const methods, so please: could somebody enlighten me? :D

If miraculously this works, can I use this instead of getters & setters or this is a bad exercise?

Comment: How would the setter work without a parameter?

Comment: @Eli I think the setter returns m_age by reference.

Comment: Using the reference which was returned. Or is this only works, if the method is inline?
@TonyJ Yes

Comment: I mean, without an implementation of any of these methods it's impossible to say.

Comment: Properties are syntactic sugar for functions. First (non-`const`) method is likely called for both because neither are invoked on a `const Person `.

Comment: @EliSadoff both just return m_age

Comment: @user4581301 oh, yes, I forgot about that.
So this is bullshit, and it's impossible to use methods with the same name instead of getters & setters?

Comment: It's actually kind of dangerous. By returning an unprotected reference to a member you are for all intents and purposes making the member `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Properties are syntactic sugar for hiding functions. So yes. You can write a function that returns a reference and get something that, on the surface, looks like a property.

But consider this: behind the property is a setter function that can (and should) do more than simply set a value. The point of any setter is to ensure that setting the value does not harm the state of the object.

By replacing the setter with a function that returns an unprotected reference to a `private` member you are stripping away this line of defense. The caller can use that reference as they see fit and to the possible detriment of the object. This might be just fine, depending on the nature of the member, but you might as well be honest. Declare the member `public`, improve readability, and save yourself the hassle of writing the function.

As for the `const` part of the question, you can sort of (and this is an ugly, simplistic sort of "sort of") think of `int& age()` as `int& age(Person * this)` and `int age() const` as `int age(const person * this)`

In OP's example, `age()` is never invoked on a constant `Person`, so there is no reason for `int age() const` to ever be invoked.

Answer (score 3):

Your code compiles well and works as intended:

```
#include <iostream>

class Person {
public:
     int& age() { return m_age; }
     int age() const { return m_age; }
private:
     int m_age;
};

int main () {
    Person p;
    p.age() = 15; //first method is called?
    std::cout << p.age(); //second method?
}
```

[See Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30e39e7a2af78a04)

---

> If miraculously this works, **can I use this instead of getters & setters** or this is a bad exercise? *(emphasis mine)*

No, this can't be used as a real replacement for a *setter* function.
Returning a reference to a member variable gives the client full control to that member variable, which is different from a *setter* like

```
void age(int newValue) {
    if(newValue > 150) {
         throw std::invalid_argument("You're older than 150? We don't believe that!");
    }
    m_age = newValue;
};
```

Comment: Hah! Beat my by 8 seconds. Teach me to proofread. Slightly different spins, though, so I'll keep my answer live.

Comment: @user4581301 May be I'm more thinking in code than in prose :P

Comment: If I could accept more than 1 answer, I would accept both, but the prose is more detailed, so I accepted that. Sorry and thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Tudvari De nada. I think these answers just constitute a good balance of prose and code now.